# TypeError: callback is not a function this error occur

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I got a error TypeError: callback is not a function

How to solve this

Below My code

```
router.post('/upload', upload.array('file',3), function (req, res, next) {
    var data = req.files;
    res.send(data);
    var docName = 'rabbit2';
    db.get(docName , function(err, body) {
        if (!err)
        {
            var doc = body;
            var docName = body._id;
            var docrev = body._rev;
            doc.service.push(data);
            db.insert(doc, docName, docrev, function (error, response) {
                if (!error) {
                    res.send(response);
                    console.log("response success",response);
                } else {
                    console.log("sad panda",error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct call for router.post is `router.post(path, callback)`.  You have `upload.array('file',3)` where the callback should be.  [Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.post.method)